# How to Include Libraries in Visual Studio code in Ubuntu-linux?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

**code in my c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include",
            "/home/kartik/open-CV/opencv-4.0.0-alpha/include",
            "/usr/local/include/opencv4",
            "/home/kartik/open-CV/opencv-4.0.0-alpha/"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "compileCommands": "<path to your compile commands.json file>",
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

**Code in tasks.json file**

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            "/t:build"
        ],
        "group": {"kind": "build", "isDefault":true},
        "presentation": {
            // Reveal the output only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

}

I changed the settings in the .json files of visual studio code as placed in the pics. But i am still unable to use openCV libraries in visual studio code.

I will be grateful, if someone can help me out in this problem. I have tried all the solutions from various websites none of them work.

Kartik

Comment: *c_cpp_properties.json* is only meant for code completion, it is not part of any build system. You need to set up your *tasks.json* to properly include and link any libraries (and/or use a build system)

Comment: Could you share a example code of the tasks.json file because all the help shows only setting libraries in c_cpp_properties.json file

Comment: In your case you'd provide these as arguments (in the `args` array) to `g++`, e.g.: `-I/home/kartik/open-CV/opencv-4.0.0-alpha/include` and the corresponding linker flags. The task you defined will call this exact command, just like if you were to compile it manually from the command line

Comment: opencvtest.cpp:1:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated. I get this error because libraries are not found